# How to detect and possibly ignore processing a bad/hung client browser request

Tags: node.js, heroku, webserver, cloud, firewall

I'm developing a node web application. And, while testing around, one of the client chrome browser went into hung state. The browser entered into an infinite loop where it was continuously downloading all the JavaScript files referenced by the html page. I rebooted the webserver (node.js), but once the webserver came back online, it continued receiving tons of request per second from the same browser in question.

Obviously, I went ahead and terminated the client browser so that the issue went away.

But, I'm concerned, once my web application go live/public, how to handle such problem-client-connections from the server side. Since I will have no access to the clients.

Is there anything (an npm module/code?), that can make best guess to handle/detect such bad client connections from within my webserver code. And once detected, ignore any future requests from that particular client instance. I understand handling within the Node server might not be the best approach. But, at least I can save my cpu/network by not rendering to the bad requests.

P.S. 
Btw, I'm planning to deploy my node web application onto Heroku with a small budget. So, if you know of any firewall/configuration that could handle the above scenario please do recommend.

Comment: In a normal situation, clients should not continuously download JavaScript files. Can you provide client and server code that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: The issue is not reproducible at all. For some unknown reason browser went into that state. I do use many javascript client libraries, like, angular, bootstrap, jquery, etc. Anyways, my original question is not to address the specific issue, but how to be prepared for similar scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's important to know that this is a pretty rare case. If your application has a very large user base or there is some other reason you are concerned with DOS/DDOS related attacks, it looks like Heroku [provides some DDOS security for you](https://www.heroku.com/policy/security). If you have your own server, I would suggest looking into [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) or [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/#desc) as load balancers for your app combined with [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). See [this tutorial](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/fail2ban/).